# Reading a record from file

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a Unicode record from binary file and stored in object, but the last byte of the buffer does not save, why?

```
b = new byte[55];

file.read(b, 0, b.length)

set(b);

    private static int sizePtr = 4;
    private static int sizeBf = 50;
    private byte deleteTag ;                    
    private byte []buf = new byte[sizeBf];    
    private byte []pointer = new byte[sizePtr];

    public void set( byte[] b) 
    {
        deleteTag = b[0];      
        Int32 l;

        for (l = 0; l < sizeOfBuffer(); l++) 
            buf[l] = b[l+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < sizePtr; i++, l++)
            pointer[i] = b[l];
    }
```

Comment: Show us the definition for `sizeOfBuffer()`. Also, any reason you aren't just using things like `Array.Copy()` instead of rolling your own byte copying loops? This seems like a very C-like way of going about the problem, that could be greatly simplified by using C# idioms and library functions.

Comment: Regarding `buf[l] = b[l+1];` - why would you skip the first entry of `b`?

Comment: @Codor presumably because b[0] is the deleteTag, I'd also guess that `sizeOfBuffer() = sizeBf` and that the 55 is made of the of the 1 + 50 + 4.

Comment: At which point is the extra byte not saved? Is it not coming in via `b`, or is it not being saved in `buf` or `pointer`?

Comment: after the file read, check the contents of b, if b[54] is the missing byte and it's empty, then the problem isn't in any of the code shown here. It'd be in the writing code instead of the reading code.

Comment: @JamesBarrass should I consider length of byte even?

Comment: You may want to read John Skeet's explanation of Unicode and .NET which provides an example in C# of how to read files. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last execution of the first loop has `l=49` (assuming `sizeofBuffer()` simply returns `sizeBf`), which makes it

```
buf[49] = b[50]
```

After that the first execution of the second loop has `l=50` and that makes your code do

```
pointer[0] = b[50]
```

Then the last execution of that loop will be

```
pointer[3] = b[53]
```

Given that, you are losing the last byte. I'd recommend changing the second loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizePtr; i++, l++)
    pointer[i] = b[l+1];
```

unless there's more processing after that which you haven't shown in your code.

Comment: `l` is 50 after the execution of the first loop making the statement `l < sizeOfBuffer()` false which is what causes the loop to stop looping. Assuming that sizeOfBuffer() returns 50

Comment: You're right of course. I'll edit my answer in a second.

Comment: @MasoudHosseini In that case please post the code of `sizeOfBuffer()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify your specific use case but I would say what you need is the [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It is useful if you want to read a binary file with data that you know the structure of. In your case it could be something like that:

```
var br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filePath));

private static int sizePtr = 4;
private static int sizeBf = 50;
private byte deleteTag ;                    
private byte []buf = new byte[sizeBf];    
private byte []pointer = new byte[sizePtr];

//read deleteTag
deleteTag = br.ReadByte();
buf = br.ReadBytes(sizeBf);
pointer = br.ReadBytes(sizePtr);
```

If your pointer is a 4byte integer value you could also do this instead:

```
pointer = br.ReadUInt32();
```

So if your binary file is quite complex the binaryReader will be very helpful.

Comment: Excuse me? If you mean you are not allowed to use these methods, please include it in your question.

Comment: by this answer whit other form could solve my problem, thanks